# Dope sheet doesn't color channels anymore

Tags: bones, groups, dopesheet

When having bone groups with colors would make these colors to show up on the Dope Sheet keyframe channels like this
[image]

This is what it's meant to look like, But now everything is a single color

[image: But now everything is a single color]

I took the first screenshot in 2.81, the 2nd in latest version, 2.92, why did this change happened? is this something you can turn back on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open user preferences.
2. Click on the Animation tab.
3. In there, you should see an option under F-curves that says *Channel group colors*. Enabling that shows the channel colors again.

[image: Channel Group Colors Option in User Preferences]

Comment: Apparently not in version 4.x anymore!